# Predefined redundant values in view Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have here a simple modal that edits user privileges. I want to show the current value of the selected user first but it seems my code is redundant in nature as it repeats. These values are not in a separate table by the way. Is there any simpler way to do this in this view?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="user_type">Privilege</label>
    <select name="user_type" class="form-control" id="">
        <?php $user_type = $user->user_type ?>
        @if ($user_type == 'Admin')
        <option value="Admin" selected>Admin</option>
        <option value="Facilitator">Facilitator</option>
        <option value="TeamLeader">TeamLeader</option>
        <option value="ScrumLeader">ScrumLeader</option>
        <option value="Member">Member</option>
        @elseif ($user_type == 'Facilitator')
        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="Facilitator" selected>Facilitator</option>
        <option value="TeamLeader">TeamLeader</option>
        <option value="ScrumLeader">ScrumLeader</option>
        <option value="Member">Member</option>
        @elseif ($user_type == 'TeamLeader')
        <option value="Admin">Admi   n</option>
        <option value="Facilitator">Facilitator</option>
        <option value="TeamLeader" selected>TeamLeader</option>
        <option value="ScrumLeader">ScrumLeader</option>
        <option value="Member">Member</option>
        @elseif ($user_type == 'ScrumLeader')
        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="Facilitator">Facilitator</option>
        <option value="TeamLeader">TeamLeader</option>
        <option value="ScrumLeader" selected>ScrumLeader</option>
        <option value="Member">Member</option>
        @else
        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="Facilitator">Facilitator</option>
        <option value="TeamLeader">TeamLeader</option>
        <option value="ScrumLeader">ScrumLeader</option>
        <option value="Member" selected>Member</option>
        @endif
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the *laravelcollective/html* package ([here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html))

You will then be able to write something like:

```
{{Form::select('user_type', $usertypearray, $user->user_type, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Where $usertypearray is a value => label array. For instance:

```
$usertypearray = ['admin'=> 'Admin', 'facilitator'=> 'Facilitator', 'teamleader'=> 'TeamLeader', 'scrumleader'=> 'ScrumLeader','member'=>'Member'];
```

(I put values in lowercase, but check if it's what the server is looking for)

Comment: I see, how do I go about in checking the current value of the user's privileges? Im sorry quite not familiar with this form yet.

Comment: @JustinF it seems you already get the value with $user->user_type . Form::select will do the rest!

Comment: I'll try that and if it's ok to ask, in my case, what should be the value of $usertypearray?

Comment: Let me try that. I understand the structure now.

Comment: I got it to work and makes code much cleaner. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

You can looping on `select` tag like this

```
  {{ Form::select('user_type',$user_type ,old('user_type'),['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is this the same package as @Lucien Dubois?

Comment: Yup it is same. If you want html tag then look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238536/select-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-in-laravel-5-4